# SMTP on IIS 7.5 spam?

Tags: iis, smtp, iis-7.5

I have some problem with SMTP server, maybe, with some robot, malware?

Log looks like this:

```
2013-07-15 19:52:52 127.0.0.1 kasandra SMTPSVC1 KASANDRA 127.0.0.1 0 QUIT - kasandra 240  100044 133 3335 99779 SMTP - - -
2013-07-15 19:55:38 127.0.0.1 kasandra SMTPSVC1 KASANDRA 127.0.0.1 0 EHLO - +kasandra 250 0 195 13 0 SMTP - - -
2013-07-15 19:55:38 127.0.0.1 kasandra SMTPSVC1 KASANDRA 127.0.0.1 0 MAIL - +FROM:<bonalax@mail.ru> 250 0 40 27 0 SMTP - - -
2013-07-15 19:55:38 127.0.0.1 kasandra SMTPSVC1 KASANDRA 127.0.0.1 0 RCPT - +TO:<bonkwald@nabu-hamburg.de> 250 0 37 34 0 SMTP - - -
```

I dont know anything about those(bonalax@mail.ru, bonkwald@nabu-hamburg.de) email adress in my software. Iam the only user of the server(I hope:) ). Connection and Relay I have restricted to only 127.0.0.1.

So I dont understand where this communication come from.

Some tips? I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: looks like something is relaying mail using your SMTP host.  You might want to turn it off until you fix that.  netstat -b  is a good place to start to look to see what is talking to 127.0.0.1:25.  You might want to require authentication for your SMTP server.  That should help stop rogue virii.

Comment: thank, netstat helps me. finally, it was shown that one web form has been under atack of some robot. form allowed fill in sending adress too.

Comment: oh cool, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a virus, the general tip to go e in your case would be something like this:

1. install an anti virus if you don't have one
2. install an anti malware
3. run windows update
4. turn on the local firewall
5. Remove unneeded services, applications and accounts from the server

Hope this helps